# FatalError Required validation not working

Tags: sxa, validation

I am using SXA 1.8, and Sitecore 9.1

I am trying to add a validation for a Date type field where it is required, and the user cannot save the item unless this field has a value, I have copied Sitecore's "Required" validator found at /sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Required, and added the following to it:
[image]

I then added this validation for the template field i wanted, like this:
[image]

However, whenever i try to save the items of that template without filling in the required field, it saves normally,and no validation warning or anything is issued. Any advice on what could be missing to achieve the goal of stopping the user from saving if this field is not filled is appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the field where you would like to use this validation?

Comment: @TamásTárnok Date type field

Comment: If you're logged in with an account that is administrator, these will be bypassed

Comment: If you show raw values on the item, does the field have a value? Some field types have values even if they're "empty."

Comment: @MarkCassidy So i must create a different role and try with that?

Comment: @DanSinclair yes i checked the raw values but they were still empty

Comment: Yes, if you want to test your validators, you're going to have to try with a non admin account. Admins can bypass them entirely.

Comment: @MarkCassidy is it an SXA thing or Sitecore 9? In Sitecore 8.2 the validators are running with admin too.

Comment: @ Mark Cassidy what role should i give to the user so that validations can be applied?