# FatalError Required validation not working in sitecore 9.1

Tags: sxa, validation

i'm using sitecore 9.1 with SXA 1.8, i had the same problem in the [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16779/fatalerror-required-validation-not-working) question, i tried to follow the solution mentioned there, i created a new user and gave him some read/write permissions while it's not an admin account but still the "FatalError" is not working although when i tried the "CriticalError" it did work.
any idea what i might be missing?

Comment: It's still a duplicate. If you need clarification, take it to comments on the original post.

Comment: @ Mark Cassidy i left a comment on the other question but got no answers

Comment: Then there's no one who knows the answer. Opening up a duplicate is not an option. Take it to our Slack channels then.